# Criando uma Sequencia de caracteres no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Então, eu tenho essa sequencia em uma coluna de uma tabela onde toda vez que eu faço uma inserção seu valor é definido por **nextval ('ptable_pr_codigo_seq' :: regclass)**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.ptable_pr_codigo_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 103
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE public.ptable_pr_codigo_seq
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Agora, como posso fazer uma nova sequencia de forma que toda vez que eu faça uma inserção, o valor não é um número auto-numérico, mas sim um caractere em um intervalo [A ~ ZZZ] (de forma que ele avance a sequencia a cada inserção)?.

```
Exemplo: Primeiro insert           = A (valor da coluna)
         Segundo                   = B
         Terceiro                  = C
         27th                      = AA
         ...
         ?Th                       = ZZZ
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Por favor, traduza a questão para o português.

Comment: RT no comentário do @8biT

Comment: Da documentação [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html]: você pode especificar opcionalmente um tipo de dado e os tipos válidos são: smallint, integer e bigint, (default bigint) portanto não é possível especificar uma string.

Comment: Mas lembre-se de que o PostgreSQL é um software livre e portanto nada impede que você crie e implemente seu próprio conjunto de rotinas de tratamento de sequences e o façam da maneira com que deseja. O código fonte está disponível em: https://doxygen.postgresql.org/

Comment: Basically it would be a "function" that would call the sequence and do a 'base conversion' an imaginary base 26, A B C D ... AA  / Basicamente seria uma "function" que chamaria a sequence e faria uma 'conversão de base' uma imaginária base 26 , A B C D ... AA...

Comment: e aí jovem ? resolveu seu problema ?

Comment: resolvido o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei qual o objetivo, e quais poderiam ser vantagens e desvantagens disso;
Nunca havia pensado nisso até ver sua pergunta e pela curiosidade elaborei a resposta. Fiz a seguinte função no postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.to_char_sequence (bigint)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
declare 

retorno varchar DEFAULT 'A';
letra varchar DEFAULT '';
xaux integer := $1;
currnum integer;

BEGIN

while (xaux > 0) LOOP

  currnum := (xaux - 1) % 26;
  letra := chr(currnum+65);
  retorno := retorno || letra;
  xaux = (xaux - (xaux + currnum+1))/26;

END LOOP;

return retorno;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Ao executar a função: `Select to_char_sequence(27)`

> 'AA'

Agora, crie uma sequência normalmente:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.teste_serie_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

E, na coluna que quer o incremento, defina o default value para:

```
to_char_sequence(nextval('teste_serie_id_seq'::regclass))
```

Pronto, vejamos o resultado:

[image: Postgresql incremendo varchar]

---

Extra: Para que fique documentado, o código da função reversa:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.from_char_sequence (varchar)
RETURNS bigint AS
$body$
declare 

retval bigint DEFAULT 0;
col varchar := upper($1);
colnum integer;
letra varchar;
len integer;
val integer;

BEGIN
retval := 0;
len := length(col);

FOR i IN REVERSE len..1 LOOP
    letra := substring(col from i for 1);
    colnum := ascii(letra)-64;
    val := colnum * ( pow(26 , (len - (i))))::integer;
    retval := retval + val;
END LOOP;

return retval;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```